# Issue while trying to format Date

Tags: ios

I am trying to fetch a date from a textbox and convert it to a specific date format, below is the code:

```
    NSString *dateStr = self.hello.text;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

However I am getting  a date one day prior to the value at day. I am new to iOS and I suspect like Java's month, day in iOS starts at 0 for the first day?

Example:

I enter `02/07/2010` in the text box. then *dateStr gives me the same value, the change occurs after formatting the value *date shows a date like: `02/06/2010`. That is one day earlier than the date entered.

Comment: show example date in your textbox.. what you got as error?

Comment: Let me edit the question

Comment: can you also show the NSLog output of the date you get?

Comment: Please show the value of the `dateStr` and the results of printing `date`.

Comment: Your issue is timeZones.

Comment: How to resolve that? I dont want any time zone. I want it to be generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set timezone as below code

```
NSString *dateStr = self.hello.text;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Comment: What difference will GMT or UTC make, I know the difference in Java however here I am not so sure about it. I think UTC would be more appropriate than GMT. Please share the knowledge :)

Comment: I always use GMT when I need it, but I guess they produce the same result. Why don't you test it?

Comment: Yes I am on it! Thanks for the guidance :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line. It is base on time zone. [See this list of time zone country(only see that three letters abbrevation in bracket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zones_by_country), Based on this list, You have to decide about use abbreviation `GMT`, `UTC` or `EST`. If you are in India, use below code.

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
```

Discussion from apple

> In general, you are discouraged from using abbreviations except for
>   unique instances such as “UTC” or “GMT”. Time Zone abbreviations are
>   not standardized and so a given abbreviation may have multiple
>   meanings—for example, “EST” refers to Eastern Time in both the United
>   States and Australia

Comment: I dont want to consider any time zone, how do I go about doing that?